# how to manually set linecolors and linetype to factor variables using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, categorical-data

This is my sample data:

```
x <- structure(list(Zeit = c(104, 104.01, 104.02, 104.03, 104.04, 
104.05, 104.06, 104.07, 104.08, 104.09, 104.1, 104.11, 104.12, 
104.13, 104.14, 104.15, 104.16, 104.17, 104.18, 104.19, 104.2, 
104.21, 104.22, 104.23, 104.24, 104.25, 104.26, 104.27, 104.28, 
104.29, 104.3, 104.31, 104.32, 104.33, 104.34, 104.35, 104.36, 
104.37, 104.38, 104.39, 104.4, 104.41, 104.42, 104.43, 104.44, 
104.45, 104.46, 104.47, 104.48, 104.49, 104.5, 104.51, 104.52, 
104.53, 104.54, 104.55, 104.56, 104.57, 104.58, 104.59, 104.6, 
104.61, 104.62, 104.63, 104.64, 104.65, 104.66, 104.67, 104.68, 
104.69, 104.7, 104.71, 104.72, 104.73, 104.74, 104.75, 104.76, 
104.77, 104.78, 104.79, 104.8, 104.81, 104.82, 104.83, 104.84, 
104.85, 104.86, 104.87, 104.88, 104.89, 104.9, 104.91, 104.92, 
104.93, 104.94, 104.95, 104.96, 104.97, 104.98, 104.99, 105, 
105.01, 105.02, 105.03, 105.04, 105.05, 105.06, 105.07, 105.08, 
105.09, 105.1, 105.11, 105.12, 105.13, 105.14, 105.15, 105.16, 
105.17, 105.18, 105.19, 105.2, 105.21, 105.22, 105.23, 105.24, 
105.25, 105.26, 105.27, 105.28, 105.29, 105.3, 105.31, 105.32, 
105.33, 105.34, 105.35, 105.36, 105.37, 105.38, 105.39, 105.4, 
105.41, 105.42, 105.43, 105.44, 105.45, 105.46, 105.47, 105.48, 
105.49, 105.5, 105.51, 105.52, 105.53, 105.54, 105.55, 105.56, 
105.57, 105.58, 105.59, 105.6, 105.61, 105.62, 105.63, 105.64, 
105.65, 105.66, 105.67, 105.68, 105.69, 105.7, 105.71, 105.72, 
105.73, 105.74, 105.75, 105.76, 105.77, 105.78, 105.79, 105.8, 
105.81, 105.82, 105.83, 105.84, 105.85, 105.86, 105.87, 105.88, 
105.89, 105.9, 105.91, 105.92, 105.93, 105.94, 105.95, 105.96, 
105.97, 105.98, 105.99, 106, 106.01, 106.02, 106.03, 106.04, 
106.05, 106.06, 106.07, 106.08, 106.09, 106.1, 106.11, 106.12, 
106.13, 106.14, 106.15, 106.16, 106.17, 106.18, 106.19, 106.2, 
106.21, 106.22, 106.23, 106.24, 106.25, 106.26, 106.27, 106.28, 
106.29, 106.3, 106.31, 106.32, 106.33, 106.34, 106.35, 106.36, 
106.37, 106.38, 106.39, 106.4, 106.41, 106.42, 106.43, 106.44, 
106.45, 106.46, 106.47, 106.48, 106.49, 106.5, 106.51, 106.52, 
106.53, 106.54, 106.55, 106.56, 106.57, 106.58, 106.59, 106.6, 
106.61, 106.62, 106.63, 106.64, 106.65, 106.66, 106.67, 106.68, 
106.69, 106.7, 106.71, 106.72, 106.73, 106.74, 106.75, 106.76, 
106.77, 106.78, 106.79, 106.8, 106.81, 106.82, 106.83, 106.84, 
106.85, 106.86, 106.87, 106.88, 106.89, 106.9, 106.91, 106.92, 
106.93, 106.94, 106.95, 106.96, 106.97, 106.98, 106.99, 107), 
    FSB_Farbe_links = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1), FSB_Typ_links = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), Fahrspurabweichung = c(-0.310505085597022, 
    -0.309542196127488, -0.308607585269534, -0.309529936571746, 
    -0.310452287873959, -0.31137463917617, -0.312296990478383, 
    -0.305541752737464, -0.296619779070938, -0.287697805404398, 
    -0.279268412031491, -0.278781032433747, -0.278293652836003, 
    -0.277806273238259, -0.27734375, -0.27734375, -0.27734375, 
    -0.27734375, -0.277307028841091, -0.276817413388985, -0.276327797936878, 
    -0.27583818248477, -0.275471723942599, -0.276415832703928, 
    -0.277359941465258, -0.278304050226587, -0.279248158987916, 
    -0.276909218709719, -0.274391656193606, -0.271874093677493, 
    -0.269594394915214, -0.270504264010528, -0.271414133105843, 
    -0.272324002201155, -0.27323387129647, -0.273848567143439, 
    -0.274378156351682, -0.274907745559925, -0.275263407198508, 
    -0.273821028496787, -0.272378649795066, -0.270936271093347, 
    -0.269582007243196, -0.271541746362726, -0.273501485482253, 
    -0.275461224601782, -0.277324467368697, -0.27683506048286, 
    -0.276345653597023, -0.275856246711185, -0.275342947128182, 
    -0.274361920959113, -0.273380894790045, -0.272399868620975, 
    -0.271129261363634, -0.265813188962985, -0.260497116562329, 
    -0.255181044161673, -0.249941348984442, -0.247632253883712, 
    -0.245323158782982, -0.243014063682255, -0.240704968581525, 
    -0.243957329572663, -0.248633233331343, -0.253309137090024, 
    -0.257757983878592, -0.256280582214447, -0.254803180550301, 
    -0.253325778886158, -0.251711166051994, -0.248298486954593, 
    -0.244885807857196, -0.241473128759795, -0.238344631661443, 
    -0.239324255485894, -0.240303879310346, -0.241283503134797, 
    -0.24192691616877, -0.238551477940446, -0.235176039712127, 
    -0.231800601483803, -0.228475938574099, -0.226995101786797, 
    -0.225514264999493, -0.224033428212189, -0.222560651396139, 
    -0.221194957055284, -0.219829262714432, -0.218463568373577, 
    -0.217097874032723, -0.21515240460553, -0.213043027496151, 
    -0.210933650386773, -0.208837716721903, -0.206905460093489, 
    -0.204973203465074, -0.203040946836663, -0.201026177776153, 
    -0.196570605181605, -0.192115032587063, -0.187659459992515, 
    -0.182792637221818, -0.173637062614099, -0.16448148800638, 
    -0.155325913398674, -0.146670502011139, -0.152096945484571, 
    -0.157523388957995, -0.162949832431427, -0.167823533370045, 
    -0.165889889828726, -0.163956246287403, -0.162022602746084, 
    -0.159963594812924, -0.154427526218816, -0.148891457624715, 
    -0.143355389030607, -0.137819320436499, -0.13671875, -0.13671875, 
    -0.13671875, -0.136388331368362, -0.131514900223315, -0.126641469078268, 
    -0.121768037933228, -0.117069961448919, -0.115114245124791, 
    -0.113158528800661, -0.11120281247653, -0.109087597656251, 
    -0.104693066406248, -0.100298535156245, -0.095904003906248, 
    -0.0916052351095185, -0.0886749615548059, -0.0857446880000976, 
    -0.0828144144453848, -0.0799165604538399, -0.0774760083970585, 
    -0.0750354563402769, -0.072594904283499, -0.0706295692129058, 
    -0.075522612621854, -0.0804156560307954, -0.0853086994397436, 
    -0.0902017428486919, -0.0903344045097887, -0.0881645669872215, 
    -0.0859947294646541, -0.0837002630065289, -0.0798347937076307, 
    -0.0759693244087383, -0.0721038551098403, -0.0683284255948609, 
    -0.0673396267086446, -0.066350827822427, -0.0653620289362091, 
    -0.0641811014836224, -0.0608144738057093, -0.0574478461277956, 
    -0.0540812184498869, -0.0507053688589885, -0.0468729880000489, 
    -0.0430406071411036, -0.0392082262821583, -0.0353758454232185, 
    -0.0309318896264039, -0.0264507605571378, -0.0219696314878779, 
    -0.0175406360967141, -0.015666190932482, -0.0137917457682524, 
    -0.0119173006040199, -0.0100428554397878, -0.00626247747066144, 
    -0.00215128450112778, 0.00195990846840011, 0.00603664571741724, 
    0.00947879557013387, 0.0129209454228458, 0.0163630952755625, 
    0.0196466142805918, 0.0210959142880107, 0.0225452142954319, 
    0.0239945143028528, 0.025643890937711, 0.0325448701669515, 
    0.0394458493961822, 0.0463468286254227, 0.0528784270446119, 
    0.0548146104399012, 0.0567507938351932, 0.0586869772304852, 
    0.0605855254897036, 0.0615665023857366, 0.0625474792817693, 
    0.0635284561778009, 0.0647462074738052, 0.0698521739162818, 
    0.0749581403587509, 0.0800641068012273, 0.0851700732436964, 
    0.088986019218912, 0.0925737786856788, 0.0961615381524406, 
    0.0996283662176822, 0.100115320517216, 0.10060227481675, 
    0.101089229116284, 0.101589879118756, 0.102564224981917, 
    0.103538570845078, 0.104512916708239, 0.105515676372029, 
    0.107985485426153, 0.110455294480273, 0.112925103534396, 
    0.115266227152696, 0.115756260271094, 0.116246293389493, 
    0.116736326507891, 0.117416481094767, 0.120304010663071, 
    0.123191540231376, 0.126079069799677, 0.128935432379541, 
    0.130331718481913, 0.131728004584287, 0.133124290686661, 
    0.134520576789033, 0.132640421681579, 0.130062855497926, 
    0.127485289314277, 0.1250530260181, 0.126534199708033, 0.128015373397963, 
    0.129496547087895, 0.130898017701937, 0.131381656024044, 
    0.131865294346152, 0.13234893266826, 0.1326290307242, 0.12820808431943, 
    0.123787137914665, 0.119366191509894, 0.115297914956724, 
    0.116269473928021, 0.117241032899319, 0.118212591870618, 
    0.119184534170744, 0.120164649589137, 0.121144765007527, 
    0.122124880425919, 0.123101959330116, 0.124030868775564, 
    0.124959778221013, 0.125888687666462, 0.126817597111909, 
    0.128719499483801, 0.130787611512604, 0.132855723541404, 
    0.134580766090116, 0.132164309751811, 0.129747853413503, 
    0.127331397075195, 0.125052047846167, 0.126530679839505, 
    0.128009311832843, 0.129487943826179, 0.130999529467622, 
    0.132932694538269, 0.134865859608913, 0.136799024679559, 
    0.138656476632385, 0.138162939208824, 0.137669401785262, 
    0.137175864361702, 0.136860652119074, 0.138783445060425, 
    0.140706238001773, 0.142629030943124, 0.144536249506591, 
    0.145003493113203, 0.145470736719816, 0.145937980326428, 
    0.14640522393304, 0.147777497774738, 0.149334351584919, 0.150891205395101, 
    0.152311024520469, 0.151822584527471, 0.151334144534473, 
    0.150845704541475, 0.150456748940469, 0.151424888625212, 
    0.152393028309955, 0.153361167994696, 0.154329985514398, 
    0.155318359078489, 0.15630673264258), Querabstand_links = c(1.64228559917915, 
    1.63554537289242, 1.62890625, 1.62890625, 1.62890625, 1.62890625, 
    1.62890625, 1.62317592872497, 1.6158284209996, 1.60848091327421, 
    1.60144864812596, 1.59949912973499, 1.59754961134401, 1.59560009295304, 
    1.59364978936117, 1.59168487487424, 1.58971996038732, 1.5877550459004, 
    1.58579061536437, 1.58383215355594, 1.58187369174751, 1.57991522993908, 
    1.5782060989426, 1.57915020770393, 1.58009431646526, 1.58103842522659, 
    1.58198253398792, 1.57630087490333, 1.57025872486465, 1.56421657482598, 
    1.55916205423693, 1.56735087609476, 1.57553969795258, 1.5837285198104, 
    1.59191734166823, 1.59457213428688, 1.59563131270336, 1.59669049111985, 
    1.59740181439702, 1.59451705699357, 1.59163229959013, 1.58874754218669, 
    1.58603901448639, 1.58995849272545, 1.59387797096451, 1.59779744920356, 
    1.6015625, 1.6015625, 1.6015625, 1.6015625, 1.60146714425636, 
    1.59950509191823, 1.59754303958009, 1.59558098724195, 1.59316890495867, 
    1.58446987739398, 1.57577084982927, 1.56707182226456, 1.55849990837511, 
    1.55480535621394, 1.55111080405277, 1.54741625189161, 1.54372169973044, 
    1.55041465914533, 1.55976646666269, 1.56911827418005, 1.57805231183812, 
    1.5760824429526, 1.57411257406707, 1.57214270518154, 1.56996684435999, 
    1.56509158850656, 1.56021633265314, 1.55534107679971, 1.55090801332289, 
    1.55286726097179, 1.55482650862069, 1.55678575626959, 1.55822148738396, 
    1.55339943277207, 1.54857737816018, 1.54375532354829, 1.53900958476547, 
    1.53703513571573, 1.53506068666599, 1.53308623761625, 1.53125, 
    1.53125, 1.53125, 1.53125, 1.53125, 1.52878329440829, 1.52561922874423, 
    1.52245516308016, 1.51931126258285, 1.51641287764023, 1.51351449269761, 
    1.51061610775499, 1.50765061419573, 1.50269997797956, 1.4977493417634, 
    1.49279870554724, 1.48684767976536, 1.47046401994102, 1.45408036011668, 
    1.43769670029236, 1.42224725402228, 1.43310014096914, 1.44395302791599, 
    1.45480591486285, 1.46462592505507, 1.46172545974309, 1.45882499443111, 
    1.45592452911913, 1.45280390802154, 1.44357712703136, 1.43435034604119, 
    1.42512356505101, 1.41589678406083, 1.4140625, 1.4140625, 
    1.4140625, 1.41353383018938, 1.4057363403573, 1.39793885052523, 
    1.39014136069317, 1.38263619217338, 1.37970261768719, 1.37676904320099, 
    1.3738354687148, 1.3707744140625, 1.3658916015625, 1.36100878906249, 
    1.3561259765625, 1.35124310018253, 1.34635931092468, 1.34147552166683, 
    1.33659173240897, 1.33177274672614, 1.32786786343529, 1.32396298014444, 
    1.3200580968536, 1.31704038842581, 1.32682647524371, 1.33661256206159, 
    1.34639864887949, 1.35618473569738, 1.35718129426468, 1.35392653798083, 
    1.35067178169698, 1.34730111000816, 1.34246927338454, 1.33763743676092, 
    1.3328056001373, 1.32806310118972, 1.32608550341729, 1.32410790564485, 
    1.32213030787242, 1.3199238949766, 1.3151144268653, 1.31030495875399, 
    1.3054954906427, 1.30066742828848, 1.29491885700007, 1.28917028571166, 
    1.28342171442324, 1.27767314313483, 1.2698337760025, 1.2618673243238, 
    1.25390087264512, 1.24603751664507, 1.24322584889872, 1.24041418115238, 
    1.23760251340603, 1.23479084565968, 1.23087185247066, 1.22676065950113, 
    1.2226494665316, 1.21844610734157, 1.21254527902263, 1.20664445070369, 
    1.20074362238475, 1.19515868095921, 1.19322628094932, 1.19129388093942, 
    1.18936148092953, 1.18710201066931, 1.17625761473765, 1.165413218806, 
    1.15456882287434, 1.14431517193308, 1.14141089684015, 1.13850662174721, 
    1.13560234665427, 1.1327738495103, 1.13179287261426, 1.13081189571823, 
    1.1298309188222, 1.12847994821992, 1.12105308793995, 1.11362622766, 
    1.10619936738003, 1.09877250710008, 1.09330122254441, 1.0881758518776, 
    1.0830504812108, 1.07816298243536, 1.07913689103443, 1.0801107996335, 
    1.08108470823257, 1.08200387088124, 1.08102952501808, 1.08005517915492, 
    1.07908083329176, 1.07806868835357, 1.07510491748862, 1.07214114662367, 
    1.06917737575872, 1.06653365861078, 1.06849379108438, 1.07045392355797, 
    1.07241405603156, 1.07391344187364, 1.07006340244924, 1.06621336302483, 
    1.06236332360043, 1.05855484016061, 1.05669312535745, 1.05483141055428, 
    1.05296969575112, 1.05110798094796, 1.05843198194632, 1.06771122020747, 
    1.0769904584686, 1.08590214932127, 1.08491470019464, 1.08392725106802, 
    1.0829398019414, 1.08203125, 1.08203125, 1.08203125, 1.08203125, 
    1.08256127235231, 1.09533289529943, 1.10810451824652, 1.12087614119364, 
    1.13274896004328, 1.13177740107198, 1.13080584210068, 1.12983428312938, 
    1.12890625, 1.12890625, 1.12890625, 1.12890625, 1.12885116566988, 
    1.12792225622444, 1.12699334677899, 1.12606443733354, 1.12513552788809, 
    1.1223504382743, 1.11924827023109, 1.11614610218789, 1.11379885494768, 
    1.12056493269493, 1.12733101044219, 1.13409708818945, 1.14055560287178, 
    1.13858409354733, 1.13661258422288, 1.13464107489843, 1.13260226829857, 
    1.1297025206926, 1.12680277308663, 1.12390302548066, 1.12112454673523, 
    1.12211162158235, 1.12309869642947, 1.1240857712766, 1.12478714682139, 
    1.12190295740936, 1.11901876799734, 1.11613457858531, 1.11328125, 
    1.11328125, 1.11328125, 1.11328125, 1.11328125, 1.11241916815017, 
    1.11138126561005, 1.11034336306993, 1.10944045095906, 1.11041733094506, 
    1.11139421093105, 1.11237109091705, 1.11321512605953, 1.11224698637479, 
    1.11127884669005, 1.1103107070053, 1.10927566845681, 1.10631054776453, 
    1.10334542707226)), row.names = c(NA, -301L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
```

I try to plot one of the two lines with different linetypes (red line). But instead of one red line with 2 different linetypes I get 2 red lines. There is also a chance that the linecolor might also change (not in this example). How can I achieve this?
Can I change the color or linetype manually depending on the factor variable?

This is the code I use but that is not working like expected. If I try to set the group to 1 I get an error.

```
library(data.table)
    library(ggplot2)
    ggplot(x) +
      geom_line(aes(x = Zeit, y = Fahrspurabweichung), colour = "black", size = 1.5) +
      geom_line(aes(x = Zeit, y = Fahrspurabweichung + Querabstand_links, color = factor(FSB_Farbe_links), linetype = factor(FSB_Typ_links)), size = 1.5)
```

Comment: One line can only be one linetype. If you need one line to change linetype, then it must be split into two lines (that can "meet" at a point and otherwise look contiguous).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is for the red line to alternate between `linetype`s based on the running value of `FSB_Farbe_links`. In `ggplot2` (among others), the `linetype=` cannot change within a line (similarly for `color=`). If you need it to vary within a line, then ... you need multiple lines.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QoMNZ.png)

Try this:

```r
x[, grp := rleid(FSB_Typ_links), by = .(FSB_Farbe_links)]
# add "group=grp" to your geom_line:
ggplot(x) +
      geom_line(aes(x = Zeit, y = Fahrspurabweichung), colour = "black", size = 1.5) +
      geom_line(aes(x = Zeit, y = Fahrspurabweichung + Querabstand_links,
                    color = factor(FSB_Farbe_links),
                    linetype = factor(FSB_Typ_links),
                    group = grp), size = 1.5)
```

[image: ggplot2 with alternating line type]

Explanation: `data.table::rleid` assigns a unique id (integer) based on the "run-length encoding" (rle) useful in grouping operations, assigning the group pairwise either the values. As a demonstration of that function, shown in a matrix solely for visualization (the return value is `integer`):

```r
vec <- c(99,99,99,105,105,105,99,102,105)
cbind(vec, rleid(vec))
#       vec  
#  [1,]  99 1
#  [2,]  99 1
#  [3,]  99 1
#  [4,] 105 2
#  [5,] 105 2
#  [6,] 105 2
#  [7,]  99 3
#  [8,] 102 4
#  [9,] 105 5
```

Where the first three `99`s are unchanging, so they are group 1. `105` is repeated 3 times as well. The next is `99` again, though since it is not contiguous with the first batch of `99`, it gets a new id. Hope that makes sense.

This method of grouping is sensitive to the order of data. If not already sorted (by `Zeit` here), then its results will be different (and likely logically incorrect). This should be a "grouped by" operation (`by=.(FSB_Farbe_links)` here); while it's feasible to also sort by the groups and achieve the same effect, it is also possible that the RLE variable `FSB_Typ_links` does not change between two different groups, which would appear as one `rle`-group. Therefore, whenever talking `rle`-like operations, I tend to urge grouping functions (whether `data.table`'s `by=.()`, `dplyr::group_by`, or base R's grouping functions such as `aggregate`/`ave`/`by`.)

`data.table::rleid` is the `data.table` convenience function that mimics somewhat the `base::rle` function, which does the same basic thing, but with a key difference:

```r
str(rle(vec))
# List of 2
#  $ lengths: int [1:5] 3 3 1 1 1
#  $ values : num [1:5] 99 105 99 102 105
#  - attr(*, "class")= chr "rle"
rleid(vec)
# [1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 4 5
```

`rle` does not assign groups, it just tells you what (`$values`) and how long (`$lengths`) for each contiguous value. You can see there that `99` has 3, `105` has 3, `99` has 1, etc.

It is easy to mimic `rleid` without the `data.table` package, if you're curious:

```r
my_rleid <- function(z) {
  r <- rle(z)
  rep.int(seq_along(r$lengths), times = r$lengths)
}
my_rleid(vec)
# [1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 4 5
```

While my base-R variant is simple, `data.table::rleid` takes half the time with this small vector and is much faster with larger datasets.

```r
bench::mark(my_rleid(vec), data.table::rleid(vec))
# # A tibble: 2 x 13
#   expression                 min  median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result  memory   time   gc     
#   <bch:expr>             <bch:t> <bch:t>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list>  <list>   <list> <list> 
# 1 my_rleid(vec)           16.1us  19.9us    36076.    17.2KB     0    10000     0      277ms <int [~ <Rprofm~ <bch:~ <tibbl~
# 2 data.table::rleid(vec)   8.3us   9.7us    93380.        0B     9.34  9999     1      107ms <int [~ <Rprofm~ <bch:~ <tibbl~
vec <- sample(1e4)
bench::mark(my_rleid(vec), data.table::rleid(vec))
# # A tibble: 2 x 13
#   expression                  min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result  memory  time   gc    
#   <bch:expr>             <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list>  <list>  <list> <list>
# 1 my_rleid(vec)           239.4us  265.6us     3135.  1016.9KB     47.7  1052    16      336ms <int [~ <Rprof~ <bch:~ <tibb~
# 2 data.table::rleid(vec)   14.7us   16.3us    51087.    39.1KB     25.6  9995     5      196ms <int [~ <Rprof~ <bch:~ <tibb~
```

(If you aren't familiar with `bench::mark`, the `\`itr/sec`` column is iterations per second, one metric for the relative speed of the functions.)

---

Note:

1. Technically, unfortunately, this method does not produce a perfectly contiguous line: at the transition from solid to dash (and vice versa), there will be a gap as big as the gap in `Zeit` With `linetype` this may be masked, since every line type except `"solid"` has gaps built in to the visual structure. However, if the gap in `Zeit` is not small, then you may notice a larger gap. To make this more evident, plot just the top (formerly red) line and use `color=` instead of `linetype=`:

   ```r
   ggplot(x) +
     geom_line(aes(x = Zeit, y = Fahrspurabweichung + Querabstand_links,
                   color = factor(FSB_Typ_links),
                   group = grp), size = 1.5)
   ```

   [image: top line only, with small gaps]

   I don't know of an easy way to mitigate this; the only way I know of is to then "copy" the first point of each contiguous group into the previous group. It is not hard (really just a `shift` operation without grouping and then reassign a couple of values, by-group), but if it isn't a problem, then I suggest sticking with the simpler more-readable approach that allows the minute gaps.

Comment: thank you very much for your detailed answer! Your solution works great. I have a little problem with the legend. If I add another `geom_line` in the same fashion like `factor(FSB_Typ_links)` it doesn't show the legend of this added line even if I put the linetype and color in the `aes()`. I know there are a lot of threads to this, but nothing helped me and I can`t make it work.

Comment: I also have the same problems with the line colors as with the line types. If I have more colors than one for one line I still get an error. I thought it would work if I use the same solution with `rleid` for the line color factor, but it actually doesn't because I can't set two groups (one for type and one for color)

Comment: `group=` needs to indicate when either linetype or color changes. If you have two rle variables `grp1` and `grp2`, try `group=interaction(grp1, grp2)`.

Comment: it works great! I already tried it and thought this wouldn't work because my graph looked so weird. The only problem that is still left is that my legend is not fully shown. I added an opposite line `FSB_Typ_rechts` to `FSB_Typ_links`. But the legend is not showing. Only the legend of `FSB_Typ_links` is in the legend, the other one is missing although I used the same syntax like before.

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution to your problem.

I transformed the dataframe so you can reduce the geom_line() calls by one.

```
x <- x %>% mutate(FahrspurabstandPlusAbstand = Fahrspurabweichung + Querabstand_links) %>% 
        pivot_longer(cols = c(Fahrspurabweichung, FahrspurabstandPlusAbstand), names_to = "name", values_to = "Fahrspurabstand")
```

As one line can't have two linetypes, I used the filter function to introduce a second line which overlays the dashed line.

```
ggplot(x, aes(Zeit, Fahrspurabstand)) +
        geom_line(aes(group = name, linetype = name, color = name)) +
        scale_linetype_manual(values = c("dashed", "solid"), guide = FALSE) +
        geom_line(data = filter(x, FSB_Typ_links == 1 & name == "FahrspurabstandPlusAbstand"), col = "red") +
        scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "black"))
```

The resulting plot looks like this[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem a while ago and solved it like this:

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(x) +
  geom_line(aes(x = Zeit, y = Fahrspurabweichung), colour = "black", size = 1.5) +
  geom_line(aes(x=Zeit,y =(Fahrspurabweichung + Querabstand_links)[ifelse(FSB_Typ_links==1, NA , T)]),na.rm=TRUE,linetype="dashed",colour = "red", size = 1)+
  geom_line(aes(x=Zeit,y =(Fahrspurabweichung + Querabstand_links)[ifelse(FSB_Typ_links==1, T , NA)]),na.rm=TRUE, linetype="solid",colour = "red", size = 1)
```

Remainig problem is, that it doesnt show up automatically in the legend.
But maybe it helps already.

Comment: A minor suggestion: add `na.rm=TRUE` to the two `geom_line` calls, as your code intentionally injects `NA` values; knowingly producing a warning and not specifically squelching it can lead one to ignoring warnings that should otherwise be noted. You know, because it is *warning* you about something that may not be expected.